# Sliding menu in a fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I'm trying to use jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu in a fragment class.

```
public class ConversionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_conversion, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(BaseActivity.context);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        menu.attachToActivity((Activity) BaseActivity.context, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.list);

        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] values = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and my list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting a null point exception at `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` What can be the cause of this?

Is this even the proper way to use jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu?

```
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089): java.lang.Exception 
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at com.example.app1.ConversionFragment.onCreateView(ConversionFragment.java:44)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-18 19:15:36.345: D/myapp(19089):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 19:15:38.001: D/AndroidRuntime(19089): Shutting down VM   
04-18 19:15:38.001: W/dalvikvm(19089): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e8b930)    
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089): java.lang.NullPointerException 
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at com.example.app1.ConversionFragment.onCreateView(ConversionFragment.java:45)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-18 19:15:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(19089):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 19:15:38.040: W/ActivityManager(389):   Force finishing activity com.example.app1/.BaseFragment
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? Why that *super.onCreate(savedInstance)* is there?

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstance)` is not meant to be there. Got carried over when I was copying pasting. It has been removed from my application. Is the logcat the stacktrace? I've added the logcat.

Comment: Yes, the log pasted is ok. Line 45 of ConfersionFragment.java is the one with __lv.setAdapter(adapter)__ ??

Comment: Yes, Line 45 is `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can't reference correctly the ListView used in the left-side of sliding menu. The problem is you are asking the wrong view (rootView) to find your list, returning in a null reference. You should inflate the menu view yourself and then invoke findViewById() on the inflated view instead, like this:

```
...
View left = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,null,false);
...
menu.setMenu(left);
...
ListView lv = (ListView) left.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
...
```

I think there are another couple of errors in your code anyway. If you want to use the sliding menu inside your fragment, you should use the menu as the returning value of the onCreateView method. For the same reason you should not attach the menu to the entire activity, so you should remove the related line of code.

Comment: k, that solves my issue. But, if I `return menu`, and remove `menu.attachToActivity(...)`, then the issue I have now is what I inflated on my conversion fragment is not shown. The only thing that is shown is then menu when I pull it from the left.

Comment: you have to set the old __rootView__ as the "content" of the sliding menu, via `menu.setContent(rootView)`

Comment: Thanks for walking me through this!